# Certain podcasts produce "video format not supported" error

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-touch, podcasts

When I sync my iPod Touch touch to iTunes to get updated podcasts, lately some have been coming back with this error:

> Some of the videos in your iTunes library, including he video "Jake and Amir: Resolutions", were not copied to the iPod "Greg's iPod" because they cannot be played in this iPod.
>
> "POV: Trying to Fall Asleep" was not copied because the video format is supported by this iPod "Greg's iPod".
>   "Jake and Amir: Dave" was was not copied because the video format is supported by this iPod "Greg's iPod".
>
> etc.

I have no idea what this is trying to tell me. I have played these podcasts in the past, and I haven't found too many others out there that are having this type of problem. I have other podcasts that are working just fine. Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with OpenDNS. Every computer in the house was seeing the same problem, but I couldn't find anyone else seeing these problems. I tried relaxing the settings as much as possible, but it wasn't until I switched to Google DNS that it resolved itself. Now, is there something I could have changed in OpenDNS that would resolve this?